# Passing log level dynamically in log4j2.xml in Mule ESB

Tags: log4j, mule

Per requirements, we want to log INFO level data in DEV and QA environemnts, but in Production and IAT environments we want to log only ERROR level data.

As per mule guidelines, we can configure log4j.xml in ${mule.home}/conf directory as we need in above mentioned environments. This way we can fulfill our requirement, but we don't have change at configure level, it requires lot of I&O team approvals.

So we want to make this change in log4j2.xml at application level. Currently I am passing a vm argument for log level as shown below.

We don't want go with this approach as well, because we need to work with I&O team to configure log.level property in servers. 
Good thing is, we have mule.env property available in all environments which has a value DEV, QA, STG and PROD.

Can you please suggest any other approach where I can evaluate  log level based on mule.env value?

```
<AsyncLogger name="org.glassfish.grizzly" level="${sys:log.level}"/>
<AsyncLogger name="org.asynchttpclient" level="${sys:log.level}"/>
<AsyncLogger name="httpclient.wire" level="${sys:log.level}"/>
<AsyncLogger name="com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly" level="${sys:log.level}"/>
<AsyncLogger name="WageGarnishment" level="${sys:log.level}"/>
<AsyncLogger name="org.mule.modules.jobtrackingservices.generated.adapters.JobtrackingservicesConnectorConnectorConfigBasicAdapter" level="${sys:log.level}"/>
<AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger" level="${sys:log.level}"/>
<AsyncLogger name="Main Flow" level="${sys:log.level}"/>
<AsyncLogger name="CDMValidator" level="FATAL"/>
<AsyncLogger name="com.adp.xyz.cdmvalidator.validator.BaseValidator" level="${sys:log.level}"/>
<AsyncLogger name="com.adp.xyz" level="${sys:log.level}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems to be possible to replace the properties at deployment time because log4j2 knows nothing about Mule properties. If you use Maven you could replace the properties at build time using the [Maven Resource plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a bean in your application which can call the logger's setLevel method to set the Log Level.
You can pass the environment name or the log level as an argument to this bean.
You can call the method using the invoke component and have this flow executed at the startup.